# How to set a custom endpoint for OPC UA Server?

Tags: python, opc-ua

The following constellation exists: A single-board computer (SBC) and an edge device are connected to a guard (via a LAN connection). An OPC UA server is already running on the Edge Device.
The SBC takes measurements, evaluates them and should now also make them available via an OPC UA server for the Edge Device. (The SBC also requires certain information from the Edge Device for the evaluation, but that is a different topic.)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpCTb.png)

I have already created a server with the various nodes I need, but when I try to set a custom endpoint, I always get this error:

```
Executing <Task pending name='Task-1' coro=<main() running at C:\...\opcua-test.py:18> wait_for=<_GatheringFuture pending cb=[Task.task_wakeup()] created at C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\tasks.py:702> cb=[_run_until_complete_cb() at C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py:180] created at C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\runners.py:100> took 1.125 seconds
OPC UA Server(opc.tcp://10.208.0.235) error starting server
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\asyncua\server\server.py", line 550, in start
    await self.bserver.start()
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\asyncua\server\binary_server_asyncio.py", line 139, in start
    self._server = await asyncio.get_running_loop().create_server(self._make_protocol, self.hostname, self.port)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1539, in create_server
    raise OSError(err.errno, 'error while attempting '
OSError: [Errno 10049] error while attempting to bind on address ('10.208.0.235', 0): die angeforderte adresse ist in diesem kontext ungültig
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\opcua-test.py", line 25, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main(), debug=True)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 194, in run
    return runner.run(main)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 664, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\...\opcua-test.py", line 18, in main
    async with server:
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\asyncua\server\server.py", line 219, in __aenter__
    await self.start()
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\asyncua\server\server.py", line 554, in start
    raise exp
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\asyncua\server\server.py", line 550, in start
    await self.bserver.start()
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\asyncua\server\binary_server_asyncio.py", line 139, in start
    self._server = await asyncio.get_running_loop().create_server(self._make_protocol, self.hostname, self.port)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1539, in create_server
    raise OSError(err.errno, 'error while attempting '
OSError: [Errno 10049] error while attempting to bind on address ('10.208.0.235', 0): the requested address is invalid in this context
```

This is how I start my server:

```
import asyncio
import logging
from asyncua import Server


async def main():
    _logger = logging.getLogger("asyncua")
    # setup server
    server = Server()
    server.set_server_name("Custom Endpoint Server")
    server.set_endpoint("opc.tcp://10.208.0.235:4850")
    # works with "opc.tcp://localhost", "opc.tcp://127.0.0.1", "opc.tcp://0.0.0.0"

    await server.init()

    async with server:
        while True:
            await asyncio.sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    asyncio.run(main(), debug=True)
```

It works with: `"opc.tcp://localhost"`, `"opc.tcp://127.0.0.1"`, `"opc.tcp://0.0.0.0"`

How to solve it with a custom endpoint?

```
server.set_endpoint("opc.tcp://10.208.0.235:4850")
```

Comment: Just double checking: Does your machine actually have that `10.208.0.235` interface? Maybe it changed through DHCP. And is there a reason you can't simply avoid this by using `0.0.0.0`?

Comment: I am assigned an IP address in "Internet Protocol, Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)". And that's why I thought I could use this as an endpoint?